# Governmental debt after COVID

Tags: macroeconomics, government-debt, research

Is there any well-researched studies published about the effect of increased governmental spending and later deepening debt burden due to COVID? Appreciate that the event is quite recent, but being the #1 topic recently, there could have been some studies already out there.

Did some research but haven't found any papers focusing on this particular aspect of the topic.

Comment: Nobody is in a position to accurately forecast either GDP, nor the level of debt. Meanwhile, the research on the effects of debt burdens even on a historical basis are controversial.

Comment: Not expecting any accurate forecast, only numerical applications on existing models. I believe in terms of GDP there are such studies.

Comment: The only one I can think of was shown to be erroneous.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: In any event, the odds are that there are any peer-reviewed publications on this topic is extremely low, purely based on the time for peer review. There’s been some academic articles on the pandemic published, it seems unlikely that any discussed fiscal implications, given the lack of information on the topic. After that, the research would largely be opinion-based, which this website tries to avoid.